# Android, decode 0x1b vAA string@BBBBBBBB outof range

Tags: android, security, assembly, dex

I try to find const-strings from byte code of an APK by finding the operation 0x1a and 0x1b. now i successfully extract strings in opcode "0x1a vAA string@BBBB" but fail to extract in "0x1b vAA string@BBBBBBBB". Finding the index of string out of range. can you tell me why?

Comment: Please post a hex dump of the bytecode that you're looking at. Also, you might find baksmali's "dump" functionality useful. e.g. with v2.2b4, "baksmali dump classes.dex > classes.dump" - which will print an annotated hex dump of the dex file.

Comment: thanks for your help, i find myself make some mistakes on "packed-switch-payload format" fail to read bytecode well, so i have a value out of range.